# Browse local image folder from an HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing an esay live blogging app.

I have a form in the backend and I can upload to the server text messages or images.

At this moment everything is working with a simple file upload field, but I want to speed up the process so:

1) reflex camera attached via USB that save images in a local folder on my mac

2) a "preview" of the folder in the backend, updating live while I shoot picture

3) when I select a shot I will upload to the server (this is not difficult).

I cannot find the right plugin to "watch" and interact a local directory. Any idea?

Comment: For security reasons you will not achieve this with any normal JavaScript. We're getting into browser plugin / Java applet / ActiveX control territory here.

Comment: In general, monitoring the client's local filesystem using JavaScript may not be a good idea, see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/371875/1344144.

Comment: what language are you using for backend?

Comment: @greatbear302 I'm using rails